# Wpf Backgammon board

Tags: .net, wpf

What are your ideas for designing backgammon board using WPF?
may i use picture for board background?
how about nuts?
thanks all.

Comment: I Want To use Picture and stack panel for layouting
what is yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My *initial* idea would be to set up a 15x3 matrix of resizable images. The leftmost and righmost of the 15 would be the inner and outer table sides of the boards and the central one would be the bar.

The three-high dimension would be the middle of the board (no image) with the triangular images when the pieces are placed at top and bottom.

Then I would see how that worked out with resizing. If no good, change it.

I'd make these all the same size except possibly the outer table edge since you don't need to put any pieces there.

Keep in mind that you need:

- space to show the dice throws and doubling cube.
- a way to offset the pieces slightly if you end up with six or more at one point.

Perhaps a good move would be to fire up the Windows backgammon game and see how it does it.

Comment: dear paxdiablo thanks for your good response it will be the best answer :)
may I use picture for background of bourd ?
what are your ideas about Nuts?

Comment: If you use a picture as a _board_ background, then you probably don't want a 15-wide matrix. If you mean a picture of a triangle for the points, you just have to make sure it's scalable (such as SVG), not a bitmappy type. If, by nuts, you mean the pieces, you could also use an scalable image for that as well though I'd proably just start by drawing simple circles to start with.